# Send a private message to all members in the list (python => discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

I would like to be able to send a private message to all the people contained in a list. I looked through the API reference but I don't seem to have found anything that could help me. Can you help me? Here is my code;

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(1014875132847738900)
    liste = role.members
    for i in range (liste):
        await ctx.liste[i].send("test")
```

I'm sure my loop hurts my eyes, but it helps to understand what I want to do ^^'

Comment: Do `range(len(liste))` instead and `liste[i].send()` without `ctx`. Or better yet mention the role instead of sending a dm to all the members.

Comment: I knew very well that I was not far away. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each element in a list in Python, without using an index, and sending to a member is as simple as [`Member.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.send).

The most readable, concise way to do this is:

```
for member in liste:
    await member.send("test")
```